# Find the column(s) name where the value of the variable matches a regex

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a data frame where I need to search for a regular expression within the data frame.

```
dim(df)
[1] 10299 561
```

I wanted to know if there is a way, I could find the name(s) of the column(s) where a particular regex may be available.

As an example, how do I find the name of the column where 'rsi' is present. I am referring to iris.

Comment: By the way, I think there have been a lot of questions of this kind over at StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you,

```
 names(iris)[apply(iris, 2, function(x) any(grepl("rsi", x)))]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I should have been able to think of that. Thanks for this simple and elegant solution.